# When using the Outlook PIA or Embedded Interop types in .NET 4 does Outlook 2010 still need to be installed?

Tags: outlook, outlook-object-model

I'm working the the Outlook (Outlook 2010) object model via the Office PIA and I need to know if I still need Outlook installed on the machine that my program executes on.  This seems like a basic requirement, but I can't find anything that says "Outlook is required to be installed in order to use the Outlook object model"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it still has to be installed.